# Как чистятся анонимный функции?

Tags: php

Вопрос до кучи, а вот кстати анонимный функции (5.3) как чистятся?
По идее же должны вычищаться?

Comment: Зачем анонимные функции чистить? Че-то непонятно что требуется... Переменные в них - также, а сами функции зачем?

Comment: @jkeks, Не следует создавать вопрос в ответе.

Comment: @Expert - это не ответ а коммент.

Я тоже отвечу вопросом на вопрос - почему у вас не возникал такой вопрос когда вы использовали "обычные" функции?

Answer (score 2):

Анонимные функции в PHP - это обычные объекты класса Closure. Соответственно и очищаются они по тому же принципу, что и остальные объекты.

Comment: Но смысла их чистить в 99.999% случаев - нет, если вам так важна производительность и т.д. - пишите на C++, С#, C, Java, Nodejs etc. 

Но, лично для меня, подобные вопросы о php звучат смешно =)

Comment: Смысл чистить их такой же, как и смысл чистить память любых других переменных - что бы избежать утечек памяти и не упереться в memory limit. 

Особенно актуально это для скриптов работающих с большими объемами данных и скриптов постоянно висящих в памяти (демонов)